# Receiving connection refused from post request during kubernetes preStop hook

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, graceful-shutdown

I am using preStop hook and execute sleep command to allow my app to shutdown gracefully. There is second thread in the app which sends post request by some interval to another application. When preStop hook starts, I receive connection refused from the http post call. What can be wrong here? Is it possible that app can send post call during preStop hook waiting in sleep ?